# In Common Lisp, how to define a generic data type specifier (like list of integers)?

Tags: common-lisp

I would like to define a type specifier that describes a list of things of the same type. So I would like to have `(list-of integer)` similar to `(array integer)` (which is built-in). I am able to create it for a specific type, like this:

```
(defun elements-are-integer (seq) 
  (every #'(lambda (x) (typep x 'integer)) seq))
(deftype list-of-integer ()
  '(and list (satisfies elements-are-integer)))
```

However, this means I have to do this for every possible type. How can I change this code so that the type would take another type as an argument, and construct the `satisfies` predicate on the fly? The problem is that the `satisfies` requires a global symbol, and I don't know how to define the predicate function in proper context (I guess I need to `gensym` it somehow, but how?). Also, the solution should work so that the type could be created inside another package.

Answer (score 18):

Try this:

```
(defun elements-are-of-type (seq type)
  (every #'(lambda (x) (typep x type)) seq))

(deftype list-of-type (type)
  (let ((predicate (gensym)))
    (setf (symbol-function predicate)
      #'(lambda (seq) (elements-are-of-type seq type)) )
    `(and list (satisfies ,predicate)) ))

(typep '(1 2 3) '(list-of-type integer))
; -> T

(typep '(1 2 a) '(list-of-type integer))
; -> NIL

(typep '(a b c) '(list-of-type symbol))
; -> T
```

Comment: Close, but `and` doesn't short-circuit, so `(typep 5 '(list-of-type t))` can throw an error because the `satisfies` runs before the `list` check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69816852/shouldnt-and-type-specifier-short-circuit

Comment: @MichaelBurge It would be obnoxious for an implementation to check the value space *before* it has checked the type space, particularly since types are generally checked at compile time and values at runtime.  But `typep` is just a regular runtime function, and a fringe one at that, so it probably shoudn't surprise us that implementations might be a bit lax.  The defensive thing to do would be to add a guard like `(and (listp seq) ...)` to the predicate.

Comment: Nice.  I changed it slightly to have outer function return a function for the sequence for my own use.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/75854669/3673 for a solution that avoids to create a symbol each time you call list-of-type for the same type.

Comment: This does not work as a type.  In particular `(typep '(1 . 2) '(list-of integer))` will signal an error, which it should not.  At the risk of blowing my own trumpet, https://stackoverflow.com/a/75854669/3673 is more nearly correct (it still has termination problems)