# How do you define a type specifier MULTIPLE-OF with a parameter?

Tags: types, common-lisp, deftype

In [ANSI Common Lisp, by Paul Graham](http://www.paulgraham.com/acl.html), page 234, there is an example type specifier :

```
(deftype multiple-of (n)
  `(and integer (satisfies (lambda (x)
                             (zerop (mod x ,n))))))
```

Unfortunately it seems to not be a valid ANSI Common Lisp as [CLHS says SATISFIES only takes a symbol](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/t_satisf.htm), it can't take a lambda :

```
CL-USER> (typep 12 '(multiple-of 4))
The SATISFIES predicate name is not a symbol: (LAMBDA (X)
                                                (ZEROP
                                                 (MOD X 4)))
   [Condition of type SIMPLE-TYPE-ERROR]
```

How can you create that `(multiple-of n)` type specifier ?

**Update**

More globally, how could you create a type specifier like (integer * *) that can optionally takes two or more parameters and run a function/lambda on it ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on [this excellent answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75854669/3673), here is how to implement MULTIPLE-OF type specifier :

```
(defun make-mof (n)
  #'(lambda (x) (zerop (mod x n))))

(defvar *mof-name-cache* (make-hash-table :test #'equal))

(deftype multiple-of (n)
  (let ((predicate-name
         (or (gethash n *mof-name-cache*)
             (let ((pn (make-symbol (with-standard-io-syntax
                                     (format nil "MULTIPLE-OF-~S" n)))))
               (setf (symbol-function pn) (make-mof n)
                     (gethash n *mof-name-cache*) pn)))))
    `(satisfies ,predicate-name)))
```

and now I can check the type like this:

```
CL-USER> (typep 12 '(multiple-of 4))
T
CL-USER> (typep 13 '(multiple-of 4))
NIL
```

Answer (score 2):

There are no additional parametera in Common Lisp to the predicate.

```
(defun multiple-of-4-p (x)
  (zerop (mod x 4)))

(deftype multiple-of (n)
  `(and integer (satisfies multiple-of-4-p)))
```

You could though write a macro which creates both the function and the DEFTYPE form.

Generally one can't provide additional parameters.

Here is an ugly hack:

```
(defun multiple-of (n-obj)
  (destructuring-bind (n . obj)
      n-obj
    (ZEROP (MOD obj n))))

(deftype multiple-of ()
  `(and (cons integer integer)
        (satisfies multiple-of)))
```

Example:

```
CL-USER 8 > (typep '(4 . 12) 'multiple-of)
T

CL-USER 9 > (typep '(4 . 13) 'multiple-of)
NIL
```

Comment: Thanks. But how could you create a type specifier like (integer * *) that can optionnaly take two parameters ? I update my question on this.

Comment: @JérômeRadix : there is no direct way to do that. See my edit...

Comment: I've succeeded in implementing MULTIPLE-OF but yes this was quite painful. See my answer.